# VSCode - как настроить что бы на сервер не попадала папка .vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, root

Существует настройка которая блокирует отправку на сервер директории с конфигами .vscode ?
Там ведь могут быть и доступы к серверу!

Вопрос связан с возможностью утечки конфига плагина
[SFTP Natizyskunk](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Natizyskunk.sftp)

Comment: Что такое «отправка на сервер»? Кто кого как отправляет?

Comment: Ctrl+S и потом по привычке правой кнопкой мыши "Upload File" как и с остальными файлами... Хоть бы предупреждение какое то сделали... на какой ... на сервере вообще нужны конфиги .vscode...

Comment: Что такое «Upload File»? В моём vscode нет такой функции

Comment: отписал разработчикам Natizyskunk / vscode-sftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует. «Писать разработчикам» не требуется - прямо в документации описано, как надо.

Собственно, в файле sftp.json указываете то, что должно быть проигнорировано.

```
{
  "remote": "dev",
  "remotePath": "/home/xx/",
  "uploadOnSave": true,
  "ignore": [".vscode", ".git", ".DS_Store"]
}
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Можете принять ответ, если вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Эту уязвимость уже во всю юзают через сервис https://leakix.net/ так что разработчики упустили этот момент, по умолчанию не должна папка с конфигами улетать на cервер! Или при Ctrl+P эти опции должны быть добавлены в sftp.json вот что я в логах взломанного сервера нашел 94.36.190.226 - - [06/Sep/2023:19:42:56 +0300 - 0.080] 404 "GET /.vscode/sftp.json HTTP/2.0" 4327 "https://leakix.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"